Passing Associative Array as parameter to a Stored Procedure using Spring Boot
I am learning Java Spring Boot and currently working on Spring Data JPA implementations.
My problem statement is that I am trying to call a procedure which is having an associative array as parameter( The array is declared within a package).
I wanted to know on the below:

How do I call a package using Spring (using JPA or JDBCTemplate)?

How do I pass an associative array as an input parameter to the procedure call from my code?
e.g. Type aa_table is Table of Varchar2(50) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER
aa_fruits aa_table
Type aa_table is declared within the package
aa_fruits is an input parameter to the Stored Procedure within the package


Kindly suggest
I am stuck at this point and not finding anything relevant

Typically we need some kind of code snippet to re-create your issue so that we can analyze it and recommend solutions. Please provide more information and code snippets.
